# Tuning Drifts in Tokamaks

Tags: fusion, magnetohydrodynamics

If we managed to make over 50 % of the drifting of the guiding centers of the gyrating particles inside a tokamak to occur into the inwards direction, away from the tokamak walls, would that allow us to get rid of that heat transfer from the plasma to the walls which is normally caused by various drifts?

I mean that as a particle circles around inside the tokamak it would be drifting inwards over half of the time.

My planned way to make the particles to drift towards the center of plasma is to have a large current in the toroidal field coils and then start to decrease that current, that would induce a poloidal electric field, which together with the toroidal magnetic field would cause a E x B drift of particles towards the center of plasma, larger drift for hotter particles - that last part sounds like violation of second law of thermodynamics, so maybe there is something wrong with this plan then.

Comment: In my understanding the major loss channel is turbulent transport and not simply drift motion as you mention it. If that would be the case, nuclear fusion reactors could be much smaller, actually fitting on a table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure such a thing is possible, but it were, all this would do is make the ions strike the inside wall instead of the outside. If you mean "towards the center of the plasma" then you face space-charge limits and simple gas pressure issues.